# Jackson Error When Doing Integration Test with Sprint Boot & GraphQL

Tags: spring-boot, junit, graphql

I'm trying to write integration tests for my GraphQL code with Spring Boot and having problems.

First, this is the library I'm using for GraphQL Spring Boot integration:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I've got all my resolvers built perfectly, I can call them from postman no problem. It's my test code where the problem comes up. I want to do integration tests, running end-to-end. For my first test, here is my GraphQL query file:

```
query {
    clients {
        id
        name
        clientKey
        enabled
        allowAuthCode
        allowClientCredentials
        allowPassword
    }
}
```

This is a perfectly valid query for my GraphQL API, I can run it from Postman successfully. Here is my test code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ClientQueryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var graphqlRestTemplate: GraphQLTestTemplate

    @Test
    fun test() {
        graphqlRestTemplate.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
        val response = graphqlRestTemplate.postForResource("graphql/getAllClients.graphql")
    }

}
```

When I run this, I get a Jackson deserialization error with my initial GraphQL request. I know it is loading my GraphQL query correctly because of the information in the error message, I just don't know why Jackson is de-serializing this incorrectly during my tests.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `graphql.kickstart.execution.GraphQLRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"query":"query {\n    clients {\n        id\n        name\n        clientKey\n        enabled\n        allowAuthCode\n        allowClientCredentials\n        allowPassword\n    }\n}\n","variables":null}')
 at [Source: (String)""{\"query\":\"query {\\n    clients {\\n        id\\n        name\\n        clientKey\\n        enabled\\n        allowAuthCode\\n        allowClientCredentials\\n        allowPassword\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":null}""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Looks an issue that was reported on May, update the latest 7.1.0,  and let me know if this issue is not fixed yet.

Comment: Nope, still not working. Upgraded to 7.1.0, did a complete mvn clean compile, everything. Still getting the same error.